# Discord.js get user by ID

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Hi I have this avatar command and I'm wondering instead of mentioning a user you could use their ID instead

```
if(command === "avatar" || command === "av") {
               const user = message.mentions.users.first() || client.users.cache.get(args[0]) || message.author
       if (!user) {
       user = message.author;
       }
      
          const member = message.guild.member(user)
          const avatar = user.avatarURL({dynamic:true})
          if (!avatar) return message.channel.send("This user doesn't have an avatar to show")
          const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
             .setTitle(`${user.username}'s avatar`)
             .setColor('RANDOM')
             .setDescription(`[Click here for the image link](${avatar})`)
             .setImage(avatar)
             .setFooter(`${client.user.username} 2021`)
             .setTimestamp()
     
         message.channel.send(embed)
```

Comment: I see you already have code to get user cache with id? is something broken or what is your question?

Comment: when i try with a user ID it just gets the message authors pfp

Answer (score 1):

instead of using `client.users.cache.get(args[0])`, I would instead recommend `message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]).user`, so it gets a member (not user), then selects the user from that member. Also make sure you have intents enabled on the developer portal, as this will not work without them.

To enable them, just select your app, then go on the bot tab, scroll down a little, and make sure both intents are checked.